# Can a product map factor up to homotopy through the fat wedge

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, universal-property

For $n \geq 2$, for $i = 1,\dots,n$, let $f_i \colon X_i \longrightarrow Y_i$ be maps of based $CW$-complexes, and consider a map
$$f \colon \prod_{i=1}^n X_i \longrightarrow \prod_{i=1}^n Y_i$$ such that $f \simeq f_1 \times \dots \times f_n$.

Denote by $FW(Y_i) = \{(y_1,\dots,y_n) \; | \; y_i = * \text{ for at least one $i$} \}$, and by $\iota \colon FW(Y_i) \longrightarrow \prod_{i=1}^n Y_i$ the inclusion.

Suppose that there exists a map $\widehat{f} \colon \prod_{i=1}^n X_i \longrightarrow FW(Y_i)$ such that $f \simeq \iota \circ \widehat{f}$.

1.) Does this imply that for some $i$, $f_i \simeq *$?

2.) This seems like an "obvious" fact. I feel like there should be a very simple proof. But I can't see a simple mathematical reason why we shouldn't be able to "homotopy the product map into the subspace consisting of the fat-wedge". Is my intuition all wrong?

Put more succinctly, can a product of non-null-homotopic maps factor up to homotopy through the fat-wedge?

I do believe that I have a proof that the answer is "no", which does seem correct, but it's more involved than such a simple statement intuitively should need, and I'm almost believing that there must be a mistake simply because intuition says that it shouldn't be this complicated. To summarise it, my proof involves proving an equivalent statement about non-triviality of a composite $*X_i \longrightarrow FW(X_i) \longrightarrow FW(Y_i)$, which I do by calculating the homotopy cofibre, and proving that it is not homotopy equivalent to $\Sigma (\ast X_i) \vee FW(Y_i),$ which I do through suspending both spaces, when they each split as a wedge, and then inspecting homology.

Comment: I maybe missing something, but doesn't the existence of your $\iota$ show that $f_i$ is homotopy equivalent to $\pi_i \circ \iota \circ \widehat{f} \circ \iota_i$, where $\pi_i$ and $\iota_i$ are the projection and injection maps for the $i$-th factor of the products. And the latter composite is a constant function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $n\geq2$ and distinct primes $p,q$ let
$$X=S^n\cup_p e^{n+1},\qquad Y=S^n\cup_q e^{n+1},$$
where the cells are attached by maps of degrees $p,q$, respectively. The inclusion
$$\iota:X\vee Y\hookrightarrow X\times Y$$
induces an isomorphism in homology. Since $X,Y$ are simply connected complexes $\iota$ is therefore a homotopy equivalence by the Whitehead Theorem.

Consider the maps
$$i:S^n\hookrightarrow X,\qquad j:S^n\hookrightarrow Y$$
which include the bottom cells. The product mapping
$$i\times j:S^n\times S^n\rightarrow X\times Y$$
deforms into $X\vee Y$. But both $i,j$ are essential.

Comment: Hi Tyrone. Thank you for the answer. I realise now that I should have stipulated that the inclusion $X \vee Y \rightarrow X \times Y$ is not a homotopy equivalence. I will obviously accept the answer anyway, but would the right thing to do be to post another question in this case?

Comment: You can alter the example. Attach to each of $X,Y$ a cell of dimension $>2n$ (keeping the notation intact).  The inclusion $X\vee Y\hookrightarrow X\times Y$ is no longer a homotopy equivalence, but it is sufficiently highly connected for the same conclusion to hold for the map $i\times j$.

Comment: Don't hurry to accept the answer if you feel that it doesn't quite capture what you are looking for. Maybe add in some details to carefully explain what extra you're looking for, and see if you can't garner any other answer.